# Open Graph Object Debugger: 302

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, sharing

There is a blog, and the latest publications were not properly shared, all the meta data specified, tried to clean the cache on FB from the bottom of the link to the result, What's keeping older articles from sharing [enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fjelvix.com%2Fblog%2Fwhat-is-3rd-party-and-how-to-visit-it-if-you-haven-t-been-on-1st)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fjelvix.com%2Fblog%2Fhow-to-create-and-manage-a-successful-company-jelvix-story

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="How to Create and Manage a Successful Company: Jelvix Story">
<meta property="og:description" content="It may seem that starting a business is a tough process that nevertheless defines the company’s success. But this statement is far from the truth. Apart from the establishment itself, the rational management strategy, talented people, and a bit of luck ar">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://jelvix.com/images/blog/59dcede572308.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://jelvix.com/blog/how-to-create-and-manage-a-successful-company-jelvix-story">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the output from the debugger, you will see that the site is redirecting to an invalid URL:

```
Fetched URL: https://jelvix.com/blog/how-to-create-and-manage-a-successful-company-jelvix-story
Canonical URL: https://jelvix.com/404
```

The crawler will try to get the og tags from the final URL which is `https://jelvix.com/404`.
You will need to ensure that the final URL contains the meta tags for the crawler to be able to get the correct values.

At the moment it looks like your site is redirecting the Facebook crawler to /404.

```
curl -A 'facebookexternalhit/1.1' https://jelvix.com/blog/how-to-create-and-manage-a-successful-company-jelvix-story
Found. Redirecting to /404
```

You can read more about the crawler here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/